# How to return a cluster with replication HA from embedded brokers to a working state without completely restarting the application?

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have raised a replication HA cluster consisting of 3 active and 3 backed up embedded brokers ActiveMQ Artemis 2.17.0.

Somehow it happened (so far it has not been possible to reproduce exactly) that the cluster got lost and stopped working correctly. The method `activeMQServerControl.listNetworkTopology()` returned the wrong topology for different nodes.

We managed to fix this only by deleting the `bindings` folder and completely restarting the entire application. Just rebooting the broker `embedded.stop() embedded.start()` didn't help.

Is it possible somehow in this case to return the cluster to a healthy state without completely restarting the application and deleting the `bindings` folder?

The configuration file of the first broker, configuration files for other brokers are similar, only other IP addresses and group names for a pair.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration xmlns="urn:activemq">
    <core xmlns="urn:activemq:core">
        <name>QM2A</name>
        <max-disk-usage>100</max-disk-usage>
        <configuration-file-refresh-period>9223372036854775807</configuration-file-refresh-period>
        <bindings-directory>${DATA}/artemis/bindings</bindings-directory>
        <journal-directory>${DATA}/artemis/journal</journal-directory>
        <large-messages-directory>${DATA}/artemis/largemessages</large-messages-directory>
        <paging-directory>.${DATA}/artemis/paging</paging-directory>
        <cluster-user>admin</cluster-user>
        <cluster-password>password</cluster-password>
        <!-- Acceptors -->
        <acceptors>
            <acceptor name="netty-acceptor">tcp://0.0.0.0:61716</acceptor>
            <acceptor name="in-vm">vm://0</acceptor>
        </acceptors>
        <security-settings>
            <security-setting match="#">
                <permission roles="admin-group" type="createNonDurableQueue"/>
                <permission roles="admin-group" type="deleteNonDurableQueue"/>
                <permission roles="admin-group" type="createDurableQueue"/>
                <permission roles="admin-group" type="deleteDurableQueue"/>
                <permission roles="admin-group" type="createAddress"/>
                <permission roles="admin-group" type="deleteAddress"/>
                <permission roles="admin-group" type="consume"/>
                <permission roles="admin-group" type="browse"/>
                <permission roles="admin-group" type="send"/>
                <permission roles="admin-group" type="manage"/>
            </security-setting>
        </security-settings>
        <connectors>
            <connector name="local">tcp://192.168.58.6:61716</connector>
            <connector name="connector9">tcp://192.168.58.9:61716</connector>
            <connector name="connector10">tcp://192.168.58.10:61716</connector>
            <connector name="connector12">tcp://192.168.58.12:61716</connector>
            <connector name="connector13">tcp://192.168.58.13:61716</connector>
            <connector name="connector14">tcp://192.168.58.14:61716</connector>
        </connectors>
        <cluster-connections>
            <cluster-connection name="my-cluster">
                <connector-ref>local</connector-ref>
                <static-connectors>
                    <connector-ref>connector9</connector-ref>
                    <connector-ref>connector10</connector-ref>
                    <connector-ref>connector12</connector-ref>
                    <connector-ref>connector13</connector-ref>
                    <connector-ref>connector14</connector-ref>
                </static-connectors>
            </cluster-connection>
        </cluster-connections>
        <ha-policy>
            <replication>
                <master>
                    <group-name>first</group-name>
                    <check-for-live-server>true</check-for-live-server>
                </master>
            </replication>
        </ha-policy>
    </core>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Why are you using a cluster of `embedded` brokers and not just one `embedded` broker?

Comment: As usual, to ensure high availability and load balancing across different nodes.  Different instances of the application with the embedded broker on different nodes.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really possible to say whether or not the problem can be resolved without restarting the application and deleting the bindings folder if there is not a clear understanding of the underlying problem. Given the details you've provided and the fact that you can't reproduce the issue we have a very incomplete picture.

Comment: Understood, if I manage to reproduce or if additional information appears, I will supplement the question. I just thought that there might be some methods to dump the data about the cluster and start the initial poll of the nodes.